# InvalidLambdaFunctionAssociationException: The function code size is larger than the maximum allowed size

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, lambda, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

While adding a Lambda function association to a CloudFront distribution I'm getting this error

```
com.amazonaws.services.cloudfront.model.InvalidLambdaFunctionAssociationException: The function code size is larger than the maximum allowed size for functions that are triggered by a CloudFront event: 4283166 Max allowed: 1048576 Function: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:xxxxxxx:function:xxxxxxxxx (Service: AmazonCloudFront; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidLambdaFunctionAssociation; Request ID: xxxxx-ee8e-4395-8655-8e49dfaa4765)
```

[image]

Comment: can you share the code its invoke Lcoudfront ?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan   please check I have edited the question and added a screenshot of CloudFront configuration. We are running an express app on this lambda function.

Comment: that means it will be invoked lambda function first then click the link, right ? it should be has `version` at the end of `Lambda Function ARN` ... example : `function:auThentications3:2` version 2

Comment: No, When I distribute the CloudFront it gives the error

Answer (score 1):

The error is quite descriptive: your lambda function is too large to be used for your chosen event trigger (Viewer Request - which has a lower size quota than Origin events, see the table below) on Lambda@Edge.

You need to make your function smaller, or find a way to achieve what you are trying to do another way.

You can find more information in the quotas table in the "[Requirements and Restrictions on Lambda Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-requirements-limits.html#lambda-requirements-see-limits)" section of the AWS CloudFront documentation. Specifically:

**Maximum compressed size of a Lambda function and any included libraries** 
Origin request and response event quotas: 50 MB 
Viewer request and response event quotas: 1 MB